# Google Earth Engine : error: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'type' in {"type":"LinearRing","coordinates":

Tags: google-earth-engine, code-review

I'm trying to export Sentinel-1 bands with this code in Google Earth Engine but I have recently this error:

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for
>   'type' in {"type":"LinearRing","coordinates":

I didn't have this problem in the past. So here is the code.

```
var start = new Date("02/05/2015");
var end = new Date("03/05/2015");

  var s1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
      .filterDate(start, end)
      //.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
      //.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
      // Filter to get images collected in interferometric wide swath mode.
      //.filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
      .filterBounds(geometry);

var count = s1.size().getInfo();

for (var i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
  var img = ee.Image(s1.toList(1, i).get(0));
  var geom = img.geometry().getInfo();
  Export.image(img.toFloat(), img.get('system:index').getInfo(), {
    'scale': 20,
    'crs': 'EPSG:32632',
    'region': geometry.toGeoJSONString()
});
}

Export.table(s1,'Sentinel1_csv');

print(Chart.image.seriesByRegion(s1, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(),'VH')
.setOptions({title: 'VH mean value over time on R3'}));
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your script that includes the geometry import.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d1d95cb611799fd308025c2995282c45

Comment: You might consider doing this exporting task in Python, as there are 561 images in the collection. EE Python in Colab is very easy to setup: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install-colab.html and you can find exporting info here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install#exporting-data . Better yet - can the analysis you'd like to perform be done all in Earth Engine?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `.toGeoJSONString()` from your export region and it should work.